# Global, recursive rename with sed fails

Tags: sed

I am attempting to search through all python files recursively down into all subdirectories and replace the word `organizations` with `organisations`. Like this:-

```
$ find . -name "*.py" | xargs sed -i 's/organizations/organisations/g'
sed: 1: "./bookings/__init__.py": invalid command code .
```

But I get an error message. How do I do this right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. Figured it out. I am using Mac OSX's `sed`, which requires that I add a "" before the `s/foo/foo_bar/g` string.

So

```
$ find . -name "*.py" | xargs sed -i "" 's/organizations/organisations/g'
```

worked.